# rdp to xrdp (debian) black screen

Tags: macos, debian, remote-desktop, xrdp

I got a new computer (client), an apple silicon mac (macos 13) if that makes a difference.
On the old computer, rdp to this server (debian) worked OK.
From the new computer the first time I tried I got an xrdp login error as I did not save the password correctly .
After fixing the password, rdp connection goes now directly to entirely black screen, the mouse cursor still looks like the mac's cursor when I move over the rdp window or click on it.
Oddly, the rdp screenshot updated correctly to show my debian's desktop during the first few tries, now it doesn't anymore, not sure if I canged something.

I tried a few commons workarounds but it didn't work.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

--- edit:
looked into  /var/log/xrdp.log
it's showing:

> [20230222-22:49:58] [INFO ] login successful for user ---- on display 12
>
> [20230222-22:49:58] [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface
> size 10296, version 4
>
> [20230222-22:49:58] [INFO ] started connecting
> [20230222-22:49:58] [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket
>
> [20230222-22:49:58] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=3783 connected to X11rdp_pid=3517 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=---------- client_port=--------
>
> [20230222-22:49:58] [INFO ] connected ok
>
> **[20230222-22:51:44] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_recv: xrdp_channel_process failed**
>
> [20230222-22:56:40] [INFO ] Received termination signal, stopping the
> server accept new connections thread

---- edit2:
also looked into /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
which shows:

> [20230222-23:09:16] [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed
>
> [20230222-23:09:16] [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs
> failed, removing trans

------- edit
sudo systemctl status xrdp

> Feb 22 23:37:34 debian xrdp[1564]: [ERROR] xrdp_sec_recv:xrdp_mcs_recv failed
>
> Feb 22 23:37:34 debian xrdp[1564]: [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_recv: xrdp_sec_recv failed
>
> Feb 22 23:37:34 debian xrdp[1564]: [ERROR] libxrdp_process_data: xrdp_rdp_recv failed
>
> Feb 22 23:37:34 debian xrdp[1564]: [ERROR] xrdp_process_data_in: xrdp_process_loop failed
>
> Feb 22 23:37:34 debian xrdp[1564]: [ERROR] SSL_shutdown: Failure in SSL library (protocol error?)
>
> Feb 22 23:37:34 debian xrdp[1564]: [ERROR] SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof
> while reading

Comment: I am not sure. May on the Debian system, uninstall XRDP, restart, instlall XRDP and then enable and start with systemctl.   To RDP into a system you normally need to log off of the system your are trying to RDP into.

Comment: Perhaps your wrong password was saved as a credential and needs to be removed. On macOS, the [Keychain Access application](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/welcome/mac) is said to be used to view, modify, and delete saved credentials.

Comment: nope... sadly reinstalling didn't work. password is not an issue either as I don't get a different outcome when I use "ask password" instead of a saved user

Comment: Try from a different computer as a Video issue between the new Mac and Debian may be the issue. I am not sure how to fix if this is the issue.

Comment: I thought of that but old computer was also a mac tho, plus I did get some screen time at the beginning as said just to get a "xrdp login error" screen, but still